# Съезжает верстка

Tags: html, css

Есть таймлайн на сайте, при попытке редактировать текст(уменьшить количество символов), вся верстка едет к чертям. Не понимаю в чем дело
CSS:

```css
.roadmap {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    
}
#road_map {
  background: #f00;
}
.roadmap_box {
    margin-top:120px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.roadmap.gradient_box {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
}
.roadmap::before {
    background-color: #26b6d4;
    content: "";
    height: 3px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    width: 100%;
}
.roadmap_icon {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 31px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -120px;
    transform: rotate(-60deg) skewY(30deg);
    width: 27px;
}
.roadmap_icon.icon_gradient_box::before {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(117,88,165,1) 0%,rgba(37,184,213,1) 99%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(117,88,165,1) 0%,rgba(37,184,213,1) 99%);
}
.roadmap_icon::before {
    background-color: #26b6d4;
    color: #ffffff;
    content: "c";
    display: block;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: inherit;
    transform: skewY(-30deg) rotate(60deg) translate(0%);
    width: inherit;
}
.rd_complete .roadmap_icon::before {
    content: "";
    font-family: ionicons;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.roadmap_inner::before {
    background-color: #26b6d4;
    content: "";
    height: 94px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -100px;
    width: 3px;
}
.roadmap_inner::after {
    background: #26b6d4 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    content: "";
    height: 15px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -6px;
    width: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.roadmap_inner {
    background-color: #26b6d4;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:20px;
}
.roadmap_box h6 {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.roadmap_box p {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:26px;
    margin: 0;
}
.roadmap .owl-prev,
.roadmap .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.roadmap .owl-prev {
    left: -33px;
}
.roadmap .owl-next {
    right: -33px;
}
.roadmap .owl-nav i {
    background-color: #26b6d4;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-size: 26px;
    height: 33px;
    line-height: 37px;
    text-align:center;
    width: 33px;
}
.roadmap .owl-prev i {
    padding-right: 3px;
}
.roadmap .owl-next i {
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.roadmap .owl-nav .disabled {
    cursor: default;
}
.roadmap .owl-nav .disabled i {
    background-color: #1C88BD;
    color: #9FB3D7;
}
.timeline_wrap {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.timeline_wrap::before {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}
.timeline_block {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}
.timeline_icon {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    line-height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    width: 20px;
}
.timeline_content {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 47%;
}
.timeline_content h6, 
.timeline_content p {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.tm_date {
    color: #46d6ff;
    font-weight: 600;
    left: 113%;
    line-height: normal;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    top: -3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.timeline_block:nth-child(2n) .timeline_content {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
}
.timeline_block:nth-child(2n) .tm_date {
    left: auto;
    right: 113%;
    text-align: right;
}
.timeline_icon.tm_complete {
    background-color: #73e080;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.v_blue .roadmap_inner::before,
.v_blue .roadmap_inner::after,
.v_blue .roadmap::before,
.v_blue .roadmap_inner,
.v_blue .roadmap .owl-nav i {
    background-color: #0f3e97;
}

.v_dark .roadmap_inner::before,
.v_dark .roadmap_inner::after,
.v_dark .roadmap::before,
.v_dark .roadmap_inner,
.v_dark .roadmap .owl-nav i,
.v_dark_light .roadmap_inner::before,
.v_dark_light .roadmap_inner::after,
.v_dark_light .roadmap::before,
.v_dark_light .roadmap_inner,
.v_dark_light .roadmap .owl-nav i  {
    background-color: #1a1c34;
}
.v_dark .roadmap .owl-nav .disabled i,
.v_dark_light .roadmap .owl-nav .disabled i {
    color: #999999;
}
```

```html
<section id="road_map" class="section_gradiant3">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12 offset-lg-2">
        <div class="title_light"> 
            <h2 class="animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.2s">Road Map</h2>
            <p class="animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.3s">Cryptominded is a curated directory of the best cryptocurrency resources. We're slowly transforming the website into the best place for beginners to learn about cryptocurrencies</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 offset-lg-2 col-md-12">
            <div class="timeline_wrap">
                <div class="timeline_block">
                    <div class="timeline_icon tm_complete">
                        <i class="ion-checkmark"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline_content animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.3s">
                        <span class="tm_date">Q1</span>
                        <h6>February 2018</h6>
                        <p>Odit, itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline_block">
                    <div class="timeline_icon tm_complete">
                        <i class="ion-checkmark"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline_content animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.3s">
                        <span class="tm_date">February 2018</span>
                        <h6>Exchange BCT to Bitcoin</h6>
                        <p>Odit, itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline_block">
                    <div class="timeline_icon">

                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline_content animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.3s">
                        <span class="tm_date">March 2018</span>
                        <h6>BCT mode of payment in Crypto</h6>
                        <p>Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline_block">
                    <div class="timeline_icon">

                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline_content animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.3s">
                        <span class="tm_date">June 2018</span>
                        <h6>Send-Receive coin mobile</h6>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quas.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="timeline_block">
                    <div class="timeline_icon">

                    </div>
                    <div class="timeline_content animation" data-animation="fadeInUp" data-animation-delay="0.3s">
                        <span class="tm_date">December 2018</span>
                        <h6>Deposit Bitcoin from your account</h6>
                        <p>Odit, itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Вот как выглядит сейчас
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как выглядит, если напротив Q1 сверху вставить Establish first Crypto-Mine и убрать текст Odit, itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @ПавелВаршавский а сейчас не можете написать?) очень сильно выручили бы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

возможно потому что блок .timeline_block имеет display:inline-block; т.е. размер зависит от содержимого.

```
.timeline_block {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

добавьте ему ширину width: 100%

Comment: Получилось, спасибо